# Error en Explode en el marco de una Function en php

Tags: php, function, explode

Tengo Una Function en php que recibe dos valores.

```
function TagRequisitos($RequiActual,$RequiAnterior){
echo "RequiActual :".$RequiActual."<br>";
$aRequiActual = explode('/', $RequiActual);
echo "aRequiActual :".$aRequiActual."<br>";
$aRequiAnterior = explode('/', $RequiAnterior);....
}
```

En la pantalla me arroja

```
RequiActual :Idioma/Puntualidad
Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/justrisc/public_html/phpAux/Funcionador.php on line 42
```

RequiActual esta perfecta porque es una string con el separador "/", Que estare haciendo mal? Porque da error el Explode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el problema es que estas intentando hacer un echo de un array. En la línea:

```
echo "aRequiActual :".$aRequiActual."<br>";
```

La función "explode" retorna un Array en base a un string separandolo o picandolo por el separador que le indiques, en tu caso: "/"

Si deseas imprimir el resultado del explode guardado en la variable "$aRequiActual" deberas hacerlo con un print_r($aRequiActual); o hacer un ciclo para imprimir cada uno:

```
foreach($aRequiActual as $valor) { 
   echo $valor; 
}
```

Consulta la documentación de la función: [Php - explode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php)

Comment: Muchas Gracias Daniel..!!!